# How to get the parents name of a control

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Is it possible to get the parent name of a control ? ex. I have a panel and there is a button inside it.

what I want is if i click the button i'll get the name of the panel.

Comment: Give the button a unique name (maybe contains parent name) and then you will not need to get the parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if the button is inside the panel (which is a container), you could get it using:

```
var panelName = myBtn.Parent.Name;
```

**Useful links:**
[Control.Parent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.parent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) which returns a [Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control(v=vs.110).aspx#Properties) object.

---

As per the comment of DaveShaw, if you're working with events you could get the parent from the `sender` argument:

```
var myBtn = sender as Button;
var panelName = myBtn.Parent.Name;
```

Comment: Could also use `sender` if the event handler has more than on button linked to it and you need to know which was clicked.